# Site is not scrolling in mobile. Using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

[This Site](http://www.ppandey.in) is not scrolling in mobile. I'm using Nexus 5 with android 6.0
Please assist me.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the relevant code in your answer.

Comment: No issues for me on mobile.